# Sparql variable outside of a block not bound inside a block

Tags: variables, union, sparql

In a Sparql query against a Sesame in-memory store, I would like to separate my query conditions, e.g. "Patient is male" from the rest of my query that produces the query result.

Let's consider this simple query:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX nci:<http://ncicb.nci.nih.gov/xml/owl/EVS/Thesaurus.owl#>
PREFIX roo: <http://www.cancerdata.org/roo/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE { 
  ?Patient a nci:C16960 . 
  ?Patient roo:100018 ?gender .
  ?gender a nci:C20197 .
  BIND(bound(?Patient) as ?bound0) .
  { 
    BIND(bound(?Patient) as ?bound1) .
  } 
  UNION { 
    ?Patient a nci:C16960 . 
    BIND(bound(?Patient) as ?bound2) .
  } 
}
```

Bound0 is always true (as expected). Bound1 is always false and Bound2 has no value in the result set at all (with and without the extra ?Patient triple).

Does that mean that the ?Patient variable is known in the first block, but not bound and that it does not exist at all in the 2nd block (even though I am declaring it again)? Why would there be a difference?

My goal is to define complex query conditions first and reduce the result set to only those patients that match all conditions. Then use the already reduced ?Patient to gather all the data that is requested in the output.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**

To illustrate my intent further, here is a more complex query. I could write the same query with OPTIONAL instead of UNION. But when I use OPTIONAL, the number of rows in the result set keeps growing fast the more hits each OPTIONAL block returns. If both blocks return multiple hits, then the result contains hits1*hits2 records. I thought I could make this more predictable and keep it within hits1+hits2 by using UNION at a high level. Is there a significant performance difference?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Patient ?Gender ?Neoplastic_Process ?MStage ?TStage
WHERE { 
 ?Patient a nci:C16960 . 
     { 
     ?Patient roo:100018 ?Gender . 
     ?Gender a ?GenderType . 
    } 
    UNION { -- SHOULD I USE OPTIONAL HERE INSTEAD (And for the block above?)
     ?Patient roo:100008 ?Neoplastic_Process . 
     ?Neoplastic_Process a ?Neoplastic_ProcessType . 
        OPTIONAL { 
         ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100241 ?MStage . 
         ?MStage a ?MStageType . 
        } 
        OPTIONAL { 
         ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100244 ?TStage . 
         ?TStage a ?TStageType . 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I suppose when I use OPTIONAL to add to the result set instead of UNION, my problem with separating the query conditions does not come into play since it is all part of the same block.

Comment: "My goal is to define complex query conditions first and reduce the result set to only those patients that match all conditions. Then use the already reduced ?Patient to gather all the data that is requested in the output." Why do you think that's even necessary? That's the job of a query optimizer. Sesame's default SPARQL engine is normally fairly good at doing this kind of optimizing for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPARQL execution is defined to be functional, ie. bottom up.  In the same way that `(1+2) * 3` means calculate `1+2`, then do `*` or `double(1+2)` means calculate `1+2` and pass `3`, not `1+2` to `double`.

```
{ 
    BIND(bound(?Patient) as ?bound1) .
}
```

is calculated then combined (with a join) with

```
?Patient a nci:C16960 . 
?Patient roo:100018 ?gender .
?gender a nci:C20197 .
```

So

```
{ 
    BIND(bound(?Patient) as ?bound1) .
}
```

has unbound `?Patient`

Engines do analyze the query and execute internally in a different way but only if it gets the same results.

It may be easier to repeat smaller patterns in the different parts of a `UNION`.  For larger patterns, to avoid repeating consider sub-SELECTs or OPTIONAL to extend results.  (The example in the question is looks like a simplification so it's hard to tell the best way.)

Comment: thanks for the info! I edited my question. My main concern is keeping the number of rows in the result set from growing rapidly and containing redundant information. Which is what happens when a lot of sub-blocks return multiple hits and using OPTIONAL. What would you say is typically better performance-wise?

Answer (score 1):

Answer after question edited.

Look at this part:

```
    OPTIONAL { 
     ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100241 ?MStage . 
     ?MStage a ?MStageType . 
    } 
    OPTIONAL { 
     ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100244 ?TStage . 
     ?TStage a ?TStageType . 
    }
```

This will yield the cross product of all the matching `?MStage`/`?MStageType` with `?TStage`/`?TStageType`.

I don't know the shape of your data but maybe this simplification will be a step on the way: you can take out all things not in the `SELECT` and simplify:

`SELECT  ?Patient ?Gender ?Neoplastic_Process ?MStage ?TStage
WHERE { 
    ?Patient a nci:C16960 . 
    ?Patient roo:100018 ?Gender . 
    ?Patient roo:100008 ?Neoplastic_Process . 
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100241 ?MStage . 
    } 
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?Neoplastic_Process roo:100244 ?TStage . 
    } 
}`

Depending on what the data looks like, and whether you need two different variables for `?MStage` and `?TStage`, other things might be possible.

Comment: Sorry about leaving the "Type" patterns in there. Usually in a query there are more patterns based on the type, which will be in SELECT, e.g. `MStageType rdfs:label ?MStageLabel`. In the simplified example above I could also use UNION to add the MStage and the TStage. 
If there is 1 Patient with 1 gender and 1 disease (Neoplastic Process) and that disease has 3 MStages and 4 TStages, OPTIONAL will produce 12 rows. If I use UNION it will produce 7. Is that assumption correct? And if so, what would be better from a typical query performance perspective?

Comment: Probably correct - I don't know your data so while it looks OK, I can't tell.  But the way it calculates less result rows also matters - depending on the engine, different operations have costs. The only way to be sure is to measure your own setup and required queries.

Comment: @AndyS Do SPARQL variables hold their value outside the block they were defined in? For example, in this code does `?MStageType` which is defined in the first OPTIONAL block hold its value in the second OPTIONAL block and be used there? Or `?Gender` in the other two?

Comment: Evaluation functional. Blocks are eval'ed and their results combined. f((1+2), (3+4)) becomes f(3,7) -- function f does not "see" (1+2), it sees 3.

A block evaluates to a solution sequence (intermediate table) which is variables+values. These as  are combined and all varibales are there. OOPTINAL is a leftjoin of the left and right sides. Which eval'ing the right-hand side of the second optional (where ?TStage is), ?MStage is not in scope but is when the optional combines left and right it is there. (FILTERs in OPTIONAl are slightly different : like SQL, we have "LEFT JOIN ON ...").